# Return one cell value based on month in another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
  I have 3 cells
    A1=5
    A2=7
    A3= 15/01/2015
    C1 = empty cell
```

what I need to show in the empty cell (C1) is :
if the month in A3 is Jan ... then return A1 value (5)
but if the month in A3 is Feb ... then return A2 value (7)

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
C1 = IF(MONTH(A3) = 1, A1, A2)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, also this equation worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Does not consider other months:

```
=IF(MONTH(A3)=1,A1,IF(MONTH(A3)=2,A2))
```